Add a line to commit message without opening the editor
I have codemod changes to multiple repositories where I have already committed the changes to all of them. But some internal prehooks aren't happy and I need to add one more line to all the commit messages like: Bug: 123456. How do I do that?
Essentially, what I have done so far

run a script to modify sources in multiple git repositories
command to git commit -am "modify xyz" for all the repositories. I used the repo tool for that.

What I should have done in step 2 was:
git commit -am "modify xyz

Bug: 123356
"


Are you just asking about git commit --amend or do you want something different?

yes git commit --amend but without opening a text editor

So git commit --amend -c @ with a custom EDITOR set, then.

@Botje git commit --amend -c "new commit message" worked. Thanks!

@jonrsharpe looks unrelated, the -c flag was what I was looking for.
